# why my telegram bot don't send message to channel when i use cronjob?

Tags: php, cron, telegram-bot, sendmessage, php-telegram-bot

hi guys i have a telegram bot and i'm try to send message to my channel.
 i want to schedule and send my posts at specific times. i try to use cronjob and some thing happen when i use cronjob it does't send message but when i manually call that url(my cronjob file in host) it send message perfectly
Here is my code i get message from database and send it!!

```
while ($row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $User_ID = $row["user_id"];
    $Caption = $row["body"] . "\n\n";
    $ChannelID = $row["channel_id"];

    $telegram->mSendMessageToChannel($ChannelID, $Caption);
    $telegram->mSendSimpleMessage($User_ID, "post sent.");

}
```

all good until here i can get post from db and every thing is good.
here is my mSendMessageToChannel method

```
 public function mSendMessageToChannel($channelID, $postText)
{
    $url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $this->token . '/sendMessage';

    $post_fields = array(
        'chat_id' => "$channelID",
        'text' => $postText
    );

    $this->executeCURL($url, $post_fields);
}
```

and here is my mSendSimpleMessage method

```
 public function mSendSimpleMessage($userId, $text)
{
    $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $this->token . "/sendMessage";
    $post_fields = array(
        "chat_id" => $userId,
        'text' => $text
    );
    $this->executeCURL($url, $post_fields);
}
```

and here is my executeCURL method:

```
 public function executeCURL($url, $post_fields)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "Content-Type:multipart/form-data"
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
}
```

and here is error i got it cannot recognize my channel:

> [15-Mar-2019 07:13:01 UTC] PHP Warning:  curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: Unable to access branio_ir in /home1/derakhtc/public_html/telegramBot/HafezederakhshanBot/telegram.php on line 85

line 85 is  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);

my bot is full admin in my channel
tnx for helping

Comment: What's in `$post_fields`??

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi  $post_fields = array(
            'chat_id' => "$channelID",
            'text' => $postText
        );

Comment: Have you tried to fix folder permissions?

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi  its an array from what i want to send to telegram api

Comment: @Guga Nemsitsveridze i dont have problem with folders

Comment: Hence it gives you error that `Unable to access` something, it may have issues with permissions

Comment: Make sure that folder has 777 permissions

Comment: no that something is my public channel id it say cannot access to it,the problem is this error happen when i use cron job but its ok when i call my cronjob file directly from brower

Comment: {"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: message text is empty"}

i'v got this now i send text parameter but it return me this